# Error trying to enable SMS MFA factor in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

After going in circles for hours in AWS documentation, I still can't find the answer.

In AWS Cognito -> MFA and verifications tab I have:

- enabled Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) and set it to `OPTIONAL`
- enabled both second factors (`SMS text message` and `Time-based One-time Password`)
- clicked the `Create role` button to create `***cognitouserpool-SMS-Role`

After I click `Save changes`, I get an error message: `You must create a SMS verification role.`

Isn't this the role I created with the `Create role` button?

If I uncheck the `SMS text message` second-factor checkbox, everything saves without error.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

P.S.: in the IAM configuration for this role, the trusted relationship looks like this (I censored the ExternalId):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "********-****-****-****-************"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `MFA and verifications`, Select `SMS text message`,

At **You must provide a role to allow Amazon Cognito to send SMS messages**

You type new role name, and click `create role` again.

**Wait some seconds**, then `save change`

Comment: Not sure if clicking `create role` again or renaming the role to `Test-SMS-Role` helped - but I'll accept your answer. Also, I heard that Uppercase for first/every word of the title might make a difference, so it's also worth a try if anyone else is having similar issues.